# Merging two sorted LinkedList using TreeSet

Tags: java, linked-list, treeset

I am trying to merge two sorted LinkedList by using TreeSet, since they already sort it themselves (Although an exception that, both the linkedList dont have common elements). The problem here is, a mysterious '0' is appended at the LinkedList I am trying to return which I am unable to ascertain.

```
Node gimmeNode(Node root, TreeSet<Integer> st){
Node temp = root;
Node toPrint = root;
Iterator it = st.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    temp.data = (int) it.next();
    temp.next = new Node();
    temp = temp.next;
}
return root;
}

Node MergeLists(Node headA, Node headB) {
Node root = new Node();
TreeSet<Integer> st = new TreeSet<>();
if(headA==null)
    return headB;
else if(headB==null)
    return headA;
else{

    while(headA != null){
        st.add(headA.data);
        System.out.println("AddedA : " + headA.data);
        headA = headA.next;

    }


    while(headB != null){
        st.add(headB.data);
        System.out.println("AddedB : " + headB.data);
        headB = headB.next;
    }
    root = gimmeNode(root, st);
    return root;
}



}
```

`Output`

```
AddedA : 1
AddedA : 3
AddedA : 5
AddedA : 6
AddedB : 2
AddedB : 4
AddedB : 7
LinkedList : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gimmeNode` has a `new Node()` at its end. This should not be the case - it should point to null. Therefore, the `new Node()`, since it's default constructed, has a 0. This is your extraneous 0. You should implement a mechanism to check if you're at the last element of the `TreeSet` - a trivial counter would do. If you're at the last element, don't set `temp.next = new Node();`, leave it `null`.

Comment: wont it.hasNext() work only if the TreeSet has an element left in it? Like while(node.next != null) so it should'nt allocate memory if it's at the end(Since the while loop wont execute at all)?

Comment: Yes, but within the last iteration of the while loop - for the last element in the set - you set `temp.next = new Node();`. This `new Node()` is the 0 you face.